# How do I convert numbers in a string to complete function in python 2.7?

Tags: string, python-2.7, int, typeerror, operands

I'm trying to write some code using functions, if/elif, and loops. I'm basing it on the Learn Python The Hard Way, exercise 35. (Python 2,7)

Where I'm currently stuck is at the def temp-function. I cant get the program to accept the user input when I enter numbers.

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex35_1.py", line 53, in <module>
    temp ()
  File "ex35_1.py", line 11, in temp
    if number in next > 5:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int

from sys import exit

def temp():
    print "Good morning."
    print "Let's get ready to kindergarden!"
    print "How cold is it outside?"

    #I think this is where the first problem is. 
        #The number-command is somehow wrong. 
    next = raw_input("> ")
    number = int(next)
    if number in next > 5:
        wool()
    elif number in next =< 6:
        not_wool()
    else:
        print "Fine, we just go!"

def wool():
    print "OK, so it is pretty cold outside!"
    print "Put on the wool."
    print "But is it raining?"
    rain = True

    while True:
        next = raw_input("> ")

        if next == "Yes":
            print "Put on the rain coat!"
            rain()
        elif next == "No" and rain:
            print "It is raining, but I dont wanna stress with the rain coat!"
            rain = False
        elif next == "No":
            print "You dont need a raincoat."
            march("With wool and no raincoat.")
        else:
            print "You should make a choice."
            exit(0)


def march(wit):
    print wit, "You are out the door!"
    exit (0)

def rain():
    print "Got the wellis?"
    march("With wool and rain stuff!")

def not_wool():
    print "There is no need for all that clothing."
    march("Remember the lunch pack!")

temp ()
```

Any tips on the mentioned error, and probable other errors would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since number is already an integer you can compare it directly.

```
number > 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You converted next to an int and assigned it to the variable number. Then you try to find that int in the original string.

Why do you need to search for the int in the string? Can't you just evaluate the int?

You could also cut out a line by converting the input to an int when you assign it to next.

Also =< should be <=

```
def temp():
    print "Good morning."
    print "Let's get ready to kindergarden!"
    print "How cold is it outside?"

    next = int(raw_input("> "))

    if next  > 5:
        wool()
    elif next <= 6:
        not_wool()
    else:
        print "Fine, we just go!"
```